# Как запускать команды в fastboot mode?

Tags: android, adb, android-adb

### Описание проблемы:

Нужно запустить команду "fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0" для того что бы планшет загружался при подаче питания.

### Что есть:

- nexus 7
- twrp
- root
- locked bootload
- android 4.2.2
- windows и linux десктопы
- нерабочий usb (по крайней мере комп его не видит, и штатными
  способами не выходит это исправить)
- планшет вклеен в торпеду машины (то есть доступа к девайсу почти
  нету, только кнопки есть)
- fastboot и adb бинарники в устройстве

### Что пробовал:

- Загружаюсь в recovery mode (twrp), запускаю консоль и пробую
  воспользоваться утилитой fastboot, но эта утилита пытается найти
  подключенный другой девайс.
- Хотел построить соединение между windows adb и планшетом посредством
  wifi adb mode. Windows определяет девайс (adb devices), подключается,
  но не авторизируется, так как авторизация доступна только через
  первое подключение через USB. Хотел обмануть первое знакомство с
  помощью virtual usb (usb over ip), но понял что это трудно и
  бессмысленно та как fastboot команды невозможно передавать через
  wifi, только adb команды, в bootload mode wifi просто недоступен

### Что нужно:

Заставить планшет загружался при подаче питания, в настройке не использовать компьютер и не пытаясь починить usb

### Рассуждения:

- TWRP ведь под капотом запускает fastboot команду flash, значит
  теоретически в recovery режиме можно запускать fastboot команды
- Может можно записать куда-нибудь fastboot команду, и при перезагрузке
  bootloader выполнит ее.
- Может можно напрямую послать команды бутлодеру (/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name) находясь в recovery режиме

Comment: Не знаю за что вам наставили плюсов за этот вопрос. Но в голове у вас полная каша и все ваши "рассуждения" не верны.

Comment: @Пионерка поэтому я и задаю вопрос, но по факту подходящего ответа не получил

Answer (score 1):

Не готов дать конкретный ответ. Могу только задать направление.

Очень интересна выдача по запросу:

```
android turn on device on plug cable
```

Может что-нибудь подойдет Вам.

Ну и способ, который должен помочь:

Находите точно такой же девайс, но с рабочим кабелем.
Делаете все желаемые действия.
Делаете полную резервную копию девайса через TWRP.
На проблемном устройстве восстанавливаете эту резервную копию на свой страх и риск.
Только не восстанавливайте разделы, которые относятся к телефонии и IMEI, иначе получите устройство без связи.

Comment: Еще лучше восстанавливайте разделы по одному. Начните с /system/ - скорее всего в нём будут отражены результаты выполнения желаемой команды.

Comment: бутлоадер залочен, для разблокировки нужен USB. Я так понимаю что поменять его я не могу, а вот вызывать его команды могу

Comment: заменить lpm картинку батареи на reboot невозможно, у меня ее просто нету, в init.rc тоже невидно что должно сработать при зарядке